# My code doesnt login after verify password code

Tags: php

Please, help me look at this code for login, I want to verify if input password matches stored harsh password. This does not work. If i comment out If (password_verify..., i will be able to login otherwise, it wont login. i dont know where i got the code wrong and it doesnt want to verify password before login

```php
if (isset($_POST['agentlogin-btn'])) {

$username= $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    function Is_email($user)
    {
        //If the username input string is an e-mail, return true
        if (filter_var($user, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    //validation
    if (strlen($_POST['username']) < 1) {

        $_SESSION['error'] = 'email or phone number required';
        header("Location:register.php");
        return;
    }

    if (strlen($_POST['password']) < 1) {
        $_SESSION['error'] = 'password required';
        header("Location:register.php");
        return;
    }

    if (!isset($_SESSION['error'])) {

        $check_email = Is_email($username);
        if ($check_email) {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM agent WHERE Email= :email  LIMIT 1";
            $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

            $stmt->execute(array(
                ':email' => $_POST['username'], 
            ));
        } else {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM agent WHERE Phone_number= :phonenumber        LIMIT 1";
            $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

            $stmt->execute(array(
                ':phonenumber' => $_POST['username'], 
            ));
        }

        if ($stmt->execute()) {
            $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $user = $result;
```

```php
            if (password_verify($password], $user['Password'])) {
                //login success
                $stmt->close();


                $_SESSION['id'] = $user['User_id'];
                $_SESSION['agentid'] = $user['agent_id'];
                $_SESSION['firstname'] = $user['First_name'];
                $_SESSION['Surname'] = $user['Surname'];
                $_SESSION['phonenumber'] = $user['Phone_number'];
                $_SESSION['email'] = $user['Email'];
                $_SESSION['verified'] = $user['verified'];
                // set flash message
                $_SESSION['success'] = "You are now logged in! Continue with your upload";

                header('location: profilepage.php');
                return;
            } else {
                $_SESSION['errors'] = "Wrong username/password";
                header('Location: register.php');
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I assume that "If the username input string is an e-mail, return true" is a comment 
(i added the `//`) - might be part of your trouble if that wasn't a copy/paste glitch

Comment: @JoSSte thats not the problem, it is a comment in my code. i mistakenly removed the comment while posting.

Comment: If `Password` is stored with `password_hash` then `Password = :password` will never match. You need to select the password, don't compare it until the function.

Comment: @user3783243 am not sure if i get what your are trying to say. In my database table, the title of the Colum where hashed password are save is  name Password. That is why i wrote, select from * where colum (Password) = input password

Comment: @Stephen `input password` <> `hashed password` though so your SQL will always fail. The `password_verify` function is written to extract the salt from the hash and use it with the input password to validate the two hashes. You can't compare the password in SQL with password_hash/password_verify.

Comment: `WHERE Email= :email AND Password = :password` this doesn't make sense. What are you doing in this line?

Comment: @Dharman, I think i am running a query to get email and password from database. What am  i suppose to do? Please, help out

Comment: @Stephen Please read my comment from hours ago. The input password will **never** equal the hashed password.

Comment: @user3783243 thanks for your time and explanation. Actually, am new into coding and am learning it online. If you can help me by telling me what to change or giving code to write, i will very grateful. Thanks and God bless you.

Comment: Delete `AND Password = :password` from queries. You  need to select that then pass it to `password_verify` to verify. `$user` also would be undefined in this code. Make sure you are fetching to that prior to using it.

Comment: @user3783243  thanks, i think i have done what you said but still, it is not working. I have edited my code. Please look at it once again

Comment: `var_dump($user)` gives back what?

Comment: @user3783243 it gives an array = array(11) { ["User_id"]=> int(78) ["agent_id"]=> string(7) "DD2SR12" ["Surname"]=> string(7) "Stephen" ["First_name"]=> string(8) "Ezeomeke" ["Other_names"]=> string(0) "" ["Email"]=> string(25) "Christ.stephaug@gmail.com" ["Password"]=> string(60) "$2y$10$um78drKAZ5JJ06QQk4TdO.KtIXEMB23MvWym.iRwbe5jdMxdtpqSy" ["Phone_number"]=> string(11) "08030799385" ["Refeeral_id"]=> string(8) "qa12zx34" ["verified"]=> int(1) ["token"]=> string(100) "9e84f2c535781fda6205147c15d067dfe0fc2a5984613769b9cb6ddb556577c0175aff949b78975ee6780083effe92cd8a34" }

Comment: Why did you add `$password = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);`? Please don't change other things. You shouldn't be doing that, `$password` needs to be plain text as was stated previously, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72337826/my-code-doesnt-login-after-verify-password-code?noredirect=1#comment127797294_72337826. Either use `$_POST['password']` or assign that to `$password` and use the variable

Comment: @user3783243 i have done that. From my var_dump($user), do you find anything that my caused my inability to login after verifying password

Comment: Hard to say`$password]` is not valid PHP so this isn't 100% your code. Need to do more debugging.

Answer (score -1):

instead of writing $stmt->execute() two times, store the result in a variable, and at second place use that variable.

Comment: How would this address the issue?